# modal box login form ajax jquery php

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for login / register using a form in modal box which appears as a pop up, ajax and jQuery to post data and php/mysql to update data in database. Please could you point me in right direction?
I have written code which opens a separate page when "login" is clicked. I am looking for functionality like
http://www.krizna.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-form-submit-using-twitter-bootstrap-modal/?demo

Also, let me know if twitter bootstrap is better or if should i use my own designs.

Answer (score 0):

For nice looking Modal Window you can use - [BootStrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)

And BootStrap is better :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap would make this easier. Check out http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/modal-with-tabbed-content for an example of how to make a login modal.